# C++ get initializer list for constructor with other parameters

Tags: c++, initializer-list

```
class V
{
private:
    int m_size;
    std::vector<int> m_list;
public:
    V(int size, std::initializer_list<int> init_list) : m_size(size)
    {
        m_list = std::vector<int>(init_list.begin(), init_list.end());
    }
};
```

I made a class which has a constructor taking multiple argument, including initializer_list. I want to use this class like

```
V v(2) = {1, 2};
```

but I'm only able to use this class like

```
V v(2, {1, 2});
```

Can't I separate arguments by non-initializer_list part and initializer_list part, like as first code I wrote?

Comment: Is the `size` argument always the same as the number of elements in the `initializer_list`? If so, you use the [`initializer_list::size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/size) member function instead. And your first syntax makes no sense, so no, you can't do that. You'll need to use nested braces.

Comment: @Praetorian Its not a direct answer of question, but it is really helpful answer. Thank you. I will use this.

Comment: So if it is indeed the size of the initializer list, then the next question is why are you storing the size in a separate variable? A `vector` keeps track of its own size.

Comment: @Praetorian I'm making a class whose constructor takes two-dimentional initializer_list, like V v = {{0, 1}, {2, 3}};. I'm worring the situation about its constructor taking invaild initializer_list, like {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4}}, so I wanted to make some kind of checking system. If syntax force user to input x-size and y-size, user will be able to see error code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your constructor to just get the `initializer_list` with:

```
class V
{
private:
    std::vector<int> m_list;
    int m_size;
public:
    V(std::initializer_list<int> init_list):
        m_list(init_list.begin(), init_list.end()),
        m_size(m_list.size()) { }
};
```

and construct V objects with:

```
V v1 = {1,2};
V v2({1, 2});
```

You don't need the size to be input anymore thanks to `std::vector`.